# Showing JSON in Java HTTP Server

Tags: java, json

I try to show my JSON in simply HTTP Java Server.

I have code:

```
        public class ServerHTTP {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
            server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
            server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
            server.start();
        }

        static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
String json = "{\"agent 1\":{\"port\":\"12345\",\"ip\":\"192.67.4.1\",\"neighbours\":{\"agent 2\":{\"port\":\"12345\",\"ip\":\"192.67.4.2\"}},\"measurements\":{\"agent 3\":{\"port\":\"12346\",\"ip\":\"192.67.4.1\"},\"power\":\"7KW\",\"voltage\":\"4.2V\"}}}";
                String response = json.toString();
                t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
                OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
                os.write(response.getBytes());
                os.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

the result is one line with JSON, I try to make something like that:

```
{
    "agent 1": {
        "port": "12345",
        "ip": "192.67.4.1",
        "neighbours": {
            "agent 2": {
                "port": "12345",
                "ip": "192.67.4.2"
            }
        },
        "measurements": {
            "agent 3": {
                "port": "12346",
                "ip": "192.67.4.1"
            },
            "power": "7KW",
            "voltage": "4.2V"
        }
    }
}
```

Is that possible with simply HTTP Server?

Comment: Sure. Add newlines.. however, creating JSON should generally be done by proper tooling (which will have options for formatting).

Comment: Also, JSON should be encoded using UTF8, not using your platform default encoding, and the Content-type header should be set to application/json;charset=UTF-8.

Comment: If I would change encoding, program can convert String to JSON format?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: do you want to get rid of quotes?

Comment: I would like to show my JSON (String) in better way, not one string.

Comment: It is dynamic string (JSON).